# Core Data trouble ordering NSSet of related objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios4

Newbie to Core Data here:

Given a patient, I want to list all the allergies for that patient.

The entity `Patient` has a to-many relationship `allergies` defined in the Object Model.

The child entity `Allergy` has an inverse relationship `patient` also defined.

`Allergy` has one attribute, `description` who's value is an NSString.

I want to get the NSSet returned by the `allergies` relationship, order it by `description`, and put into an array instance variable that will be mapped to the table view.

The code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"description" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];  
NSSet *unorderedAllergies = [selectedPatient valueForKey:@"allergies"];  
NSArray *sortedArray = [unorderedAllergies sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];  
[allergiesArray addObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];
```

Notes:  `selectedPatient` is an instance variable of the parent NSManagedObject `Patient` that was passed in from a previous controller.  `allergiesArray` is the array I want mapped to the table view.

The problem occurs at:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unorderedAllergies sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

The debugger shows an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` at this line and the app crashes.  My guess is it has to do with the related objects being lazily loaded by Core Data (i.e. "faulted objects").

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`description` is a method name of NSObject that returns a string describing the object. It is the method called when you use NSLog to log an object. All classes that inherit from NSObject already have a `description` method.

Don't use `description` as a attribute or property name because you might not get what you expect. Use `allegryDescription` or something similar to change the property name to something that won't conflict.

Comment: +1 Good catch. I think everyone gets bitten by this at some point -- "description" is a natural name for an attribute.

Comment: I agree.  Great catch.  Thank you!